# Axapta: How to populate a grid?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

in Dynamics Ax, how can i programmaticaly populate a grid ?
I think, using a datasource ... ok, but how to assign 'the query' to the datasource, then populate grid ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not like what you think, the datasoure will contain only one Table and when you assign a Datasource to the Grid AX will us the relations to filter the records, for example if you put SalesTable to Datasource and SalesLine to another DataSource, then set one gride for SalesTable DataSource and another one for SalesLine DataSource, when you select one row from SalesTable it'll select only the SalesLine related to this record.

In bottom line don't think of Form Datasorce is like Report Datasource.